# multiple select with drop down

Tags: javascript, php, html

Bellow is my code i want multiple selection with drop down and check box,when i use multiple attribute in select tag is generating the list type of view which i dont want so please help me
i want out put which is shown in the this url http://demo.itsolutionstuff.com/demo/demo-bootstrap-jquery-multiple-select-with-checkboxes-example-using-bootstrap-multiselectjs-pluginexample.html
but it is not working in my project and i am using codeigniter framework

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
    <div class="form-group">                            
        <label for="LS_name">Loan/Scholarship</label>
                        <?php 
                        $LSList = [];
                        if(isset($_REQUEST['LS_name'])){
                            $LSList = $_REQUEST['LS_name'];
                        }
                        ?>
                         <select class="form-control" name="LS_name[]" id="languages">
                            <?php foreach($LS_List as $key => $value){ ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $value['name']; ?>" <?php if(in_array($value['name'], $LSList)){ ?>selected="selected"<?php } ?>><?php echo $value['name']; ?></option><?php
                            } ?>
                         </select>
                    </div>      
                </div>
```

and i am using this script

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js">
  </script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js">
 </script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#languages').multiselect({
     includeSelectAllOption: true
    });
 });
```

Comment: Cn u pls format the question properly?

Comment: i edited my question so please help me

Answer (score 0):

I think multiselect.js Jquery plugin not provide `includeSelectAllOption` option like you use

Do like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/multi-select/0.9.12/css/multi-select.min.css">
<a href='#' id='select-all'>select all</a>
<a href='#' id='deselect-all'>deselect all</a>
<select multiple="multiple" id="my-select" name="my-select[]">
      <option value='elem_1'>elem 1</option>
      <option value='elem_2'>elem 2</option>
      <option value='elem_3'>elem 3</option>
      <option value='elem_4'>elem 4</option>
      <option value='elem_100'>elem 100</option>
    </select>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/multi-select/0.9.12/js/jquery.multi-select.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#my-select').multiSelect();
        $('#select-all').click(function(){
          $('#my-select').multiSelect('select_all');
          return false;
        });
        $('#deselect-all').click(function(){
          $('#my-select').multiSelect('deselect_all');
          return false;
        });
    });

</script>
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/nidhi_akbari_1994/jctqnuhs/) is here

Hope it will help you

Comment: thank you, That is not problem without that also it is giving output like list type only..i want drop down list with multiple selection and i have multi select plugin also...